# Why is it unparsable date with timezone WAT in Java9?

Tags: java

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
df.parse("Tue Nov 09 18:04:07 WAT 2021");
```

[image: Error]

Works fine with Java8. But not with java9. Using JDK 9.0.4

---

I am happy to get the alternate solutions. But definitely existing applications breaks just upgrading to java 9.0.4. I would like to know the reasons for this and a way to handle without much change throughout the application.

In the same online IDE, code works for java 9.0.1

[image: Breaks everywhere - Java 10]

Working scenarios:

[image: Java 11]

Comment: So not longer use the old and outdated `SimpleDateFormat` class. Use `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`

Comment: Now that you've updated the format to match input, your code works for me

Comment: @MadProgrammer My bad, it was copy-paste mistake. By the way, I am trying this with Java9. I will check the behaviour with Java8.

Comment: Also the missing Locale can be a problem

Comment: With your updated question, code works fine for me. Your earlier question was missing 'EEE' in the format to represent day, perhaps that was the issue which caused exception.

Comment: Try `DateTimeFormatter df = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern('EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy', Locale.US )`

Comment: @Jens It badly breaks. Kindly check the version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that the error is related to an important change that was introduced in Java 9 regarding the use of [CLDR locale data by default](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/9-relnotes.html#JDK-8008577):

> In JDK 9, the default locale data uses data derived from the Unicode
> Consortium's Common Locale Data Repository (CLDR). As a result, users may
> see differences in locale sensitive services behavior and/or translations.
> For example, CLDR does not provide localized display names for most 3-
> letter time zone IDs, thus the display names may be different from JDK 8
> and older. The JDK continues to ship with the legacy JRE locale data and
> the system property `java.locale.providers` can be used to configure the
> lookup order. To enable behavior compatible with JDK 8, the system property
> can be set with:
>
> `-Djava.locale.providers=COMPAT,SPI`
>
> For more detail, refer to the [JEP 252](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/252).

I was able to reproduce the issue with an installed JDK 9.0.4 version and in [the online editor](https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler/) you showed in your screenshot and JDK 10.0.1.

The problem seems related to the time zone `z` placeholder, only to certain time zones - it works fine with `UTC` or `CET`, for instance, but not for `WAT` - and only to certain locales. Using `SimpleDateFormat` or `DateTimeFormatter` makes no difference.

Consider the following test case:

```java
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.US);
df.parse("Tue Nov 09 18:04:07 WAT 2021");
```

The error is raised because it seems that `SimpleDateFormat` is unable to find a matching time zone for `WAT` [when processing](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk9/blob/010e1a3eaeda82230561dbc8620595263f0e4c87/jdk/src/java.base/share/classes/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.java#L1702-L1771) the time zone information for the provided locale.

Consider for instance the use case of `Africa/Lagos`. According to [IANA time zone database](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/3fdd3c482f9b5b724db0fddd7c134d403086454f/africa) for a long time it has always had `WAT` as time zone. But in JDK 9.0.4, debugging the above code fragment code, you will find the following information:

[image: Africa/Lagos time zone JDK 9.0.4]

As you can see, it seems associated with `CAT` and not `WAT`.

This can be checked as well using the following code:

```java
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Africa/Lagos");
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.US);
System.out.println(formatter.format(ZonedDateTime.now(tz.toZoneId())));
```

It will output:

```
Sat Dec 11 12:30:53 CAT 2021
```

In contrast, with JDK 11, for example, you will find the following time zone information for it:

[image: 'Africa/Lagos` time zone JDK 11]

And the aforementioned code will output - note the change to `WAT`:

```
Sat Dec 11 12:33:05 WAT 2021
```

As indicated in the Oracle documentation, setting the system property `java.locale.providers` to `COMPAT,SPI` will rearrange the locale providers and make your code work, but it looks certainly strange.

Please, be aware that the results described are for the locale `US`. According to the [CLDR data](https://cldr.unicode.org/index/downloads), you can find several locales for which the `WAT` time zone is applicable and even with Java 9.0.4 the code should work properly. Consider for instance:

```java
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", new Locale("en", "ZW"));
df.parse("Tue Nov 09 18:04:07 WAT 2021");
```

As described, this behavior is reproducible as well with Java 10.0.1. Please, see the error screenshot:

[image: error screenshot]

If you provide the suggested values for the `java.locale.providers` system property, note the change in the code, everything runs smoothly:

[image: successful execution]

Having said that, I am missing the reason why it starts to fail - as far as understand, it should have been [since](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8008577) the first version of Java 9, but it seems to work with Java 9.0.1 - and why it works properly in Java 11. Some clues: the IANA database changed from [2017b](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/9-0-1-relnotes.html) to [2017c](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/9-0-4-relnotes.html) between Java versions 9.0.1 and 9.0.4, respectively, and especially that [JDK 11 uses CLDR version 33](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/11-relnote-issues.html#JDK-8202537).

I sincerely hope someone can shed some light on this missing piece of the puzzle.

Comment: @Gibbs I finally was able to test the code against a JDK 9.0.4 and it fails as well. Please, see the updated answer. The proposed solution worked properly with this JDK too,. Were you able to test it?

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, I will update you on the working part for my scenario soon.

Comment: Thank you very much @Gibbs. Yes please,  would appreciate it a lot, thank you.